# write huge date to excel file in perl

Tags: perl

```
use Excel::Writer::XLSX;
my $workbook = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new('test.xlsx');
$workbook->set_optimization();
my $row = 0;
my $col = 0;
$row++;
my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();
foreach ( sort { lc($a) cmp lc($b); } keys %hash ) {
    my $value = $_;
    $col = 0;
    my @array = split( '\t', $value );
    foreach my $val (@array) {
        $worksheet->write( $row, $col, $val );
        $col++;
    }
    $row++;
}
$workbook->close();
```

I have stored huge data (>70MB) in a hash and by using above code I am gonna write data to excel file. But its showing out of memory error. Kindly help me to fix the this issue.thanks

Comment: How are you generating the hash that is giving you the 'out of memory' error? If using Excel::Writer::XLSX is causing the out-of-memory error, why don't you create a CSV or tab-delimited file and then import it into Excel?

Comment: You might want to do memory profiling. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1360142/223226

Comment: I read data from excel and done some calculation and stored in hash. now i have to write the data to excel with required information[Template]

Comment: Please post the code that is creating the hash, too.

Comment: Below code will create hash                                                                for my $row (1..$max_rows)
   {
      my @array=();
    for my $col(1..$max_cols){
     my $value= $worksheet->{'cell'}[$col][$row];
     if($col>2&$col<15){
      $value=$value*"1000000"; 
     } 
      #print $value."\t";   
      push @array,$value;
    }
    
    my $string = join("\t",@array);
    $hash{$string}=1;

   }

Answer (score 1):

Excel::Writer::XLSX shouldn't be causing an "out of memory" issue since you are using [set_optimization()](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Excel-Writer-XLSX/lib/Excel/Writer/XLSX.pm#set_optimization()) mode which reduces memory usage down to a [small and constant value.](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Excel-Writer-XLSX/lib/Excel/Writer/XLSX.pm#SPEED_AND_MEMORY_USAGE)

However, loading a 70 MB file into a hash might (depending on your system).

Perhaps you can restructure your program to read (and then write) the data one row at a time without loading everything into memory.

Comment: Looking at the code snippet that you posting in the comments to your question above it looks like you are also reading the data from an Excel file. A few comments on that: 1. It is probably the Excel reading and hash building that is burning up your memory. 2. If you are using Spreadsheet::ParseExcel to read the Excel file then that can consume a lot of memory. See the docs for information on how to reduce that. 3. Why bother storing the information in a hash. Why not just write it to the Excel file as you read it (in combination with item 2).